# Login ID/Password for SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I want to use SQLPlus but it is asking me for login id and password.

I installed it using this link https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html#ic_winx64_inst and it didn't ask me to setup a login id/password.

What is the default login id/ password?

Answer (score 2):

You installed a client.

Now you're using that client to connect to a database.

That database has users with passwords. Those users own objects, that you can query with SQL using a tool like SQLPlus.

Downloading and running client tools like you have doesn't give you a database, or anything in it.

You need to find an existing one to connect to, or you need to build your own

When you create a database - using our Database Creation Assistant (DBCA), you are prompted for a password for the default admin accounts (SYS and SYSTEM.)